# I am trying to get vscode extension gitlab workflow to connect, but get invalid url error

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

When I launch VSCode with the GitLab workflow extension, I get this error message:

```
Invalid URL: git@gitlab.com:#####/######.git/
```

(I have removed address with #).

If I right click and open folder in terminal, I can `git push`.
When I set up extension, I accepted the GitLab instance and pasted my personal access token.
Do you think I cloned the wrong URL?

Comment: I snipped the [tag:git] tag since this is not a *Git* issue. It's probably not a Git*Lab* issue either, and is probably exclusive to whatever extension you've installed in VSCode. My best guess is that whoever wrote the extension didn't realize that `user@host:path/to/repo.git` is valid ssh syntax. If changing the URL to `ssh://git@gitlab.com/<same path>` makes the warning go away, that's the case, otherwise it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is about [GitLab VS Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gitlab.gitlab-workflow), code at [`gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension)

First, you should not paste a token for an SSH URL: a token is only used as password for HTTPS URL.

Second, this is followed by [`gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension` issue 385](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/385) (initially about HTTPS URL, but with questions around SSH URL as well)

It recommends:

- checking the `gitlab.instanceUrl` setting, or the presence of `instanceUrl` in your VS Code `settings.json`.
- reviewing the extension logs (CMD+SHIFT+P and enter GitLab: Show extension logs command)
- trying to start the VS Code editor, but make sure that the GitLab sidebar is hidden during the start (make sure that you are on, for example, the "explorer" tab when you are closing the VS Code editor so it will start on the "explorer" tab): just to avoid any extension initialization bug.

---

The error:

```
[info]: Found gitlab.com in the PAT list and git remotes, using it as the instanceUrl
```

was seen in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension` issue 307](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/307).
And lead to [issue 281](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/281).

> I suggest telling it clearly on the readme to avoid group name in the URL configuration as it is taken from the workspace name.

---

Note that [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#multiple-account-support-for-gitlab-workflow-in-vs-code) (May 2022) offers an alternative:

> ### Multiple account support for GitLab Workflow in VS Code
>
> When setting up [GitLab Workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow) for VS Code, you must provide a token to authenticate to GitLab. This token authenticates you to your GitLab instance as a particular user for checking out code, seeing issues, reviewing merge requests, and more.
>
> In [GitLab Workflow 3.44](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3440-2022-05-13), you can now use multiple tokens to authenticate to the same GitLab instance. This can be great for users who have both work and personal accounts, or accounts with separated duties.
>
> We’ve also improved key storage for tokens, which will now be stored in VS Code’s SecretStorage, and is backed by your operating system keychain.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/create-multiple-account-support-vscode.png -- Multiple account support for GitLab Workflow in VS Code]
>
> See [Documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension#setup) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/298).

---

And See [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#gitlabcom-sign-in-for-gitlab-workflow-for-vs-code) (June 2022) adds:

> ### GitLab.com sign-in for GitLab Workflow for VS Code
>
> Getting started with [GitLab Workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow) for VS Code has been challenging: install the extension, only to learn you needed to follow several extra steps to set the extension up properly. The most difficult aspect of getting started was generating a personal access token with the right scope and adding it to the extension.
>
> Release [v3.47.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3470-2022-06-08) of GitLab Workflow now supports OAuth for GitLab.com, removing the need to manually generate a token. This is a huge step in making it easier for you to start using GitLab inside of VS Code.
>
> [image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E19O1N71DEE]
>
> See [Documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/tree/main#setup) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4363).

Comment: It seems to be adding a / at the end for the invalid url?

Comment: @DaleWemyss Indeed. Do you see any `instanceUrl` i your VSCode settings?

Comment: Not in settings.json Here is my gitlab output

Comment: Not in settings.json. Tried installing from scratch, but still had appdata directory. Part of my gitlab output:  ``TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: git@gitlab.com:wemyssweb/wemyssweb.git/` and this is repeated at the end.  `[info]: Found https://gitlab.com in the PAT list and git remotes, using it as the instanceUrl

Comment: Only has default url  https://gitlab.com